# What is the syntax to create files symlinks in android source tree?

Tags: android-source

I want to create a symbolic link from /system/xbin/file to /system/bin/file_link. What do I have to write in my vendor .mk file, please?

Comment: sorry my poor english, please ... from /system/xbin/file to /system/bin/file_link

Answer (score 0):

you can use `symlink()` that's within `unistd.h`:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int symlink(const char  *name1, const char *name2);
```